# How can I shorten my CMS URL

Tags: php, web, visual-web-developer

I'm a web developer and currently working on a cms project where I need to create a CMS to allow the client to add client pages on it. Here is my question regarding this project:

```
http://www.qrgtech.com/qrg/?c=ITMaster
```

The above url was generated when I created a page through cms. I want to shorten this url to look like following,

```
http://www.qrgtech.com/ITMaster
```

I just want to remove `qrg/?c=` string whenever I create a new page in my CMS. I'm working in PHP..

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: @Sushan, if I could downvote that comment, I would.

Comment: So you created the CMS? I think you need to have a look at htaccess.

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: Look into mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache, then you need to use a `.htaccess` file — which uses `mod_rewrite` so make sure this Apache extension is enabled. Depending on what CMS you're using, there may already be an option for doing this.

There are [lots](http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/) of [resources](http://www.noupe.com/php/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know.html) on the Internet that [explain](http://mod-rewrite-cheatsheet.com/) how to rewrite pages.

---

If you're using nginx or another, then you'll need to [Google similar terms](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=nginx+mod+rewrite) to get other help there.

---

And for IIS use Microsofts very own [documentation](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Comment: That is if its an apache server

Comment: You can bet your bottom dollar it is though.

Comment: Use Microsofts documentation for this then: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite